# How do i make an object visible behind a specific object?

Tags: objects

Imagine a green suzanne have an eyebrow
[image: Green suzanne]
after sometime suzanne grew hair
[image: Green suzanne with hair]

my question is how do i make suzanne eyebrow visible even though the eyebrow is obstructed/blocked by the hair in rendered view?

Comment: should eyebrow be always visible in front of everything else, or only in front of the hair?

Comment: only in front of the hair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it with render layers and compositor.

Set Suzanne, Eyebrows, and hair on 3 different layers.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Create 3 render layers with these different objects in them. Here a single example, just do the same for the others.

[image]

Then you go to the compositor, press *Use Nodes*, and set up the following nodes:

[image]

Don't forget to set the film transparency :

[image]

Then, select all the involved layers, and render your scene.

Comment: Of course, you may want to change this setup in order to take the rest of your scene into account.

Comment: Although technically correct, shadows of the eyebrows are missing, right? Seems to me that the question is pointless (in an aesthetic sense).

Comment: I think all the shadows are here since I did not Chek any layers in the exclude section  of my render layers. I do not have the file anymore and am away from my computer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.8 layers converted into collections, but everything else is the same.

Split object into 3 collections:

[image]

View layers is in top right corner, add 3 here:

[image]

Use checkbox icons to set visibility for each layer:

[image]

Enable Film -> Transparency:

EEVEE:

[image]

Cycles:

[image]

Compositing is same as before, except that there is a dedicated workspace for compositing:

[image]

Comment: Great demo, great answer, very Appreciated. Thanks.